# Escaping Non Alphanumeric Characters in C# for CSV

Tags: c#, csv, escaping

I have this as part of a string in C#:

```
!"£$$$$$$%&
```

It should end up as:

```
!,",£,$$$$$$,%,&
```

I have code which puts in a comma at every point the character changes, so that part is sorted.

However, when this output is opened up in a CSV file it is messed up because Excel doesn't like things like `"`.

How can I easily escape the characters causing the issue?  I am guessing I need to do something like:

```
String.Replace("\"","X")
```

Comment: Create a document in Excel containing `"`, save it as CSV, and see what it looks like, so that you can send `"` as `"` instead of another character? (Note that Excel's implementation of CSV uses regional settings, and your CSV file would not open in Excel on my system, as my regional settings' list separator character is `;`, not `,`.)

Comment: Did you try what you thought you might need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Out of excel the quotes are written as """" (4 quotes) to a CSV --> a string containing an escaped quote

this leads to following expression:

```
String.Replace("\"","\"\"\"\"")
```

this will *display* in excel a single quote, but you will have to know that your *data* is changed.